# Sinthatica with JFrame resizing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

Can't center JPanel on running mode and sinthatica theme. It's not centered. without synthatica theme it's working. what is the problem ?

#### My code :

```
//center code
TAB_PANEL1.setLocation((this.getWidth() - TAB_PANEL1.getWidth()) / 2,TAB_PANEL1.getX());
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The LAF should not affect the way a layout manager works. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem. We should be able to test with the default LAF as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
TAB_PANEL1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo%28java.awt.Component%29

> If the component is null, or the GraphicsConfiguration associated with this component is null, the window is placed in the center of the screen. The center point can be obtained with the GraphicsEnvironment.getCenterPoint method.

Answer (score 0):

You example does not contain enough information. First question is: what layout manager are you using? If none (that means absolute layout aka position yourself) you should use "setBounds(x,y,w,h)" like so:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

But if you expect to center-of-the-screen the JPanel; that won't work. JPanels must be nested inside a JFrame or JDialog.